# JavaScript Prototype Superclass

Tags: javascript, inheritance

So I'm working on a project and I want to have a Site superclass that houses methods and data for multiple pages - the pages having their own constructor that extends the Site superclass. 
Currently I have a constructor function that has it's own dedicated methods for it's use that is used on multiple pages. Something like this:

```
function MyFeatureConstructor () {
// some shared data for this feature
};
MyFeatureConstructor.prototype.init = function (args) {
// initialize 
}
MyFeatureConstructor.prototype.clickEvent = function (e) {...}
// other stuff specific to this feature

function SomePageConstructor () {
// shared data for this page
}
SomePageConstructor.prototype.init = function (args) {
// initialize
}
SomePageConstructor.prototype.clickEvent1 = function (e) {...}
// other stuff for this page
```

From there I call them

```
var a = new MyFeatureConstructor; // call this on the same page as SomePageConstructor
a.init(args)
var b = new SomePageConstructor;
b.init(args)
```

Except the 'MyFeatureConstructor' is used among other pages.
So I'm not quite sure how to move it from it's own constructor function to a set of methods for the Site class. I thought of just taking the methods and placing them on the constructor of the Site superclass, but then that might cause some conflicts later on. I also thought of placing them in a plain object, but then they're not so much exclusive to the feature itself, more like just a bunch of static methods.

I don't feel that it's a appropriate to place a constructor function in the Site class, is it?
Maybe I'm over thinking this?

Comment: Have you considered requireJS? Could be an overkill if you have only this one example, but in my opinion it is worth the effort in general.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this doesn't have to be done with inheritance. It sounds like you could use a helper object that contains a handful of functions that you need access to across multiple pages. You could do something like:

```
var myHelperFunctions = {
  func1: function(){ your code here },
  func2: function(){ some other code here};
}
```